# Digits after the decimal point are being replaced by zero

Tags: java, android, sorting

I would like to grab the highest number of a list of prices coming from a json file. To do so I sorted my prices with the code below . Unfortunately the code return the price sorted but without the digits after the decimal point could someone explain me why please and help me to solve this issue

```
private List<ItemObject> returnParsedJsonObject(String result) {
    List<ItemObject> jsonObject = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    JSONObject resultObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    ItemObject newItemObject; //interior object holder
    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        System.out.println("Preparsed JSON object " +
                resultObject.toString());

        // set up json Array to be parsed
        jsonArray = resultObject.optJSONArray("Bluesy_Music");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int counter = 0;
    String oneObjectsItem= new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = null;
        try {
            jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //get all data from stream

            String sold = jsonChildNode.getString("SOLD");
            String title = jsonChildNode.getString("TITLE");
            String artist = jsonChildNode.getString("ARTIST");
            String country = jsonChildNode.getString("COUNTRY");
            String company = jsonChildNode.getString("COMPANY");
            float price = jsonChildNode.getInt("PRICE");
            String year = jsonChildNode.getString("YEAR");
            newItemObject = new ItemObject(sold, title, artist, country, company, price, year);
            jsonObject.add(newItemObject);
            //show all title
            counter++;
            //getting the most price of the most expensive CD
            pricelist.add(price);
            Collections.sort( pricelist, Collections.reverseOrder());
            //getting the title of the most expensive CD
            expensivecd = (float) pricelist.get(0);
            if(price==expensivecd){
                expensivetitle = title;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //data title counter
    data.append(counter);
    return jsonObject;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using the `getInt(String)` method on the price, effectively casting it to an int and losing its scale. What you need to use is `getDouble(String)` and that should solve your issue.

Comment: thank you(sorry for the delay of my answer, the last time it did not upload)